# how to upload photo in react native android

Tags: android, reactjs, upload, native

I use react native to develop in android. And I want upload a file or photo to server .And I use react-native-file-uploader,And I got errors:

> [undefined is not an object(evaluating
>   '_reactNative.NativeModules.FileUploader.upload')]，[Cannot read
>   property 'upload' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnInu.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dztVQ.png)

please help,Thanks!
bellow is my code:

```
 import React from 'react';
    import {
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Platform,
    DeviceEventEmitter
    } from 'react-native';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import FileUploader from 'react-native-file-uploader'

const settings = {
/* uri,
uploadUrl,
method, // default to 'POST'
fileName, // default to 'yyyyMMddhhmmss.xxx'
fieldName, // default to 'file'
contentType, // default to 'application/octet-stream'
data: {
// extra fields to send in the multipart payload
}*/ 
  };

export default class NewDishView extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        avatarSource:'./src/images/support.png'
    }
}
goBack(){
    this.props.navigator.pop();
}

render(){
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.header}>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.goBack()} style={styles.back}>
                    <Icon style={styles.backIcon} name="chevron-left" />
                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <View style={{flex:1}}>             
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Create new dish</Text>
                </View>
            </View>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={
                FileUploader.upload(settings, (err, res) => {
                  // handle result
                }, (sent, expectedToSend) => {
                  // handle progress
                })
            }>
                <Text>upload</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

header:{
    flexDirection:'row',
},
back:{
    paddingLeft:10,
    paddingTop:5,
    width:25,
},
backIcon:{
    color:'#000',
    fontSize:20,
},
title:{
    fontSize:20,
    textAlign:'center',
},
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem: https://github.com/farmisen/react-native-file-uploader/issues/11. Basically, make sure it got linked properly in MainApplication.java (i.e. include the RCTFileUploaderPackage() in the getPackages() method).